# What is the exact meaning of 'beneath'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

[image]

In my county, I learned that beneath means the underside.
When the ball sticks to the base of the table, we say that the ball is beneath the table.Is that right? I want to know the exact meaning of 'beneath'?

Comment: It never exactly means ***the** underside*, because that's a noun usage, and *beneath* is always an adverb, preposition, or adjective. The nearest alternative is ***underneath***, which is similar to *beneath*, but can also be used as a noun. For example, [*The top side was worn and smooth, but **the underneath** was flaky and sharp.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+the+underneath+was%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: I want to know the exact preposition when something(ex:gum..) is stick to the underside of something(ex: table...)

Comment: In my opinion, *under* would be good enough. It could be a bit counter-intuitive, but if you talk about gum and the underside of something, chances are *on* would be the best choice. For example, [Bubble Gum on My Shoe](https://books.google.com/books?id=d2B12fIQgi4C&pg=PA5).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know the exact preposition when something(ex:gum..) is stick
>   to the underside of something(ex: table...)

In that case, *beneath* is not the correct word. We would not say that the gum is sticking beneath the table.

We would say as you have said, that the gum is sticking to the underside of the table, or *on the underside* of the table.  I know of no one word that means "on the underside" or "to the underside".

A teacher might say to the class:

**Don't be sticking your chewing gum *up under* your desks!**

Answer (score 0):

"beneath", preposition and adverb, is a more elevated variant for "under".
"beneath" and its variant "underneath" are used in written language rather than in spoken language.